# Replacing substring with another substring provided in the command line arguments without strstr in C

Tags: c

Essentially when I run this program like this:

```
./main "this biscuit is nice" biscuit tea
```

the program will print out: `This tea is nice`

however if I run it like this:

```
./main "this tea is nice" tea biscuit
```

I get a segmentation fault. I understand that I need to malloc and realloc somewhere I just have no idea where I am meant to do so.

```
/* function to act as strlen */
int Len(char* c)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; c[i] != '\0'; i++)
        ;
    return i;
}
/* function that finds and replace substring with another substring */
void replace(char mainStr[], char sub[], char new_str[])
{
    int mainLen, subLen, newLen; /* stores length of strings */

    int i = 0, j, k;
    int flag = 0, start, end;
    mainLen = Len(mainStr);
    subLen = Len(sub);
    newLen = Len(new_str);

    for (i = 0; i < mainLen; i++)
    {
        flag = 0; /* to check if any match was found */
        start = i;
        for (j = 0; mainStr[i] == sub[j]; j++, i++)
            if (j == subLen - 1)
                flag = 1; /* match was found */
        end = i;
        if (flag == 0)
            i -= j;
        else
        {
            for (j = start; j < end; j++)
            {
                for (k = start; k < mainLen; k++)
                    mainStr[k] = mainStr[k + 1];
                mainLen--;
                i--;
            }
            for (j = start; j < start + newLen; j++)
            {
                for (k = mainLen; k >= j; k--)
                    mainStr[k + 1] = mainStr[k];
                mainStr[j] = new_str[j - start]; /* replace with new sub-string */
                mainLen++;
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char* main = argv[1]; /* initialise main string */
    char* sub = argv[2]; /* initialise substring to be replaced */
    char* new = argv[3]; /* initialise new substring */

    system("clear"); /* clears the screen */
    printf("replace: %s -> %s\n", argv[2], argv[3]);
    replace(main, sub, new);
    printf("String after replacing is as:%s\n", main);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your specific question: is `main` a function or a pointer? Suggestion: avoid using the same identifier for different purposes.

Comment: Suggestion: rather than trying to change `argv[1]` in place, use a different array to where you copy the parts you need.

Comment: Where are your includes? Yes, they matter.

Comment: Indeed, to be able to handle cases where the replacement text is longer than the substring to be replaced, you *cannot* modify the original full string in-place.  If you need to construct a string exhibiting the substitution then you will need to allocate space for the result dynamically.  But do you really need to construct such a string in the first place?  If you need only print the substituted result then the answer is no: you could instead just print the potion of the original string up to the start of the sub, then the replacement, then the tail of the original string after the sub.